# How to temporarily capture stdout of my own process on Linux?

Tags: linux, qt, qt4, posix, stdout

I'm trying to display output of a method in QTextWidget.  The method prints json on stdout, and it's a part of a 3rd party code that I can't change.

Look's like this:

```
int iperf_json_finish(struct iperf_test *test)
{
    char *str;

    str = cJSON_Print(test->json_top);
    if (str == NULL)
        return -1;
    fputs(str, stdout);
    putchar('\n');
    fflush(stdout);
    free(str);
    cJSON_Delete(test->json_top);
    test->json_top = test->json_start = test->json_intervals = test->json_end = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

So, how I can do that? I'm using qt 4.8 and can't use things like QMessageLogContext.

Comment: Is it possible that you **modify** that function, or are you asking how to **redirect** `stdout` to a `QTextWidget` without modifying the shown function?

Comment: @Andreas This is api, so I can't modify that.

Comment: I think that will be a challenge then - maybe this posting helps: http://blog.debao.me/2013/07/redirect-current-processs-stdout-to-a-widget-such-as-qtextedit/

Comment: @Andreas Thank's for your time, but I'm on Qt4 and Linux.

Comment: There is POSIX solution too. View link from @Andreas

Comment: That should be fine - `QWindowsPipeReader` which is mentioned in the posting is only used with the MS-Windows variant. The Posix (Unix/Linux) variant uses `QSocketNotifier` instead which is available for Qt4

Comment: @user3355317 Your use of the term API is very much non-standard. Just because something is an API doesn't imply that you can't change it. You've just showed us the source code, so that means you do have the sources, so obviously you could modify them (say duplicate & modify).

Comment: On a side note, a completely different approach would be to write your own versions of `fputs` and `putchar` and make sure that the linker finds these symbols before the respective ones from `libc`. I am not sure though which of those solutions is more hacky ;)

Answer (score 0):

> How to temporarily capture stdout of my own process on Linux?

The trick is to replace the stdout file descriptor with the descriptor of your own pipe, intercept the output with the pipe, and then put original the stdout back.

General scheme on *NIX platforms is:

1. Save the original file descriptor of the `stdout`: `int orig_stdin = dup(1);`
2. Prepare a pipe: `pipe(cap_stdout);`
3. Do not forget to flush the stdio: `fflush(stdout);`
4. Replace the `stdout` with the writing end of the pipe: `dup2( 1, cap_stdout[1] );`
5. Start an extra thread reading from the `cap_stdout[0]` file descriptor. This is where the intercepted data are captured.
6. Call the 3rd party library function.
7. Flush the stdio: `fflush(stdout);`
8. Signal the reading thread to terminate.
9. Restore the stdin: `dup2( orig_stdin, 1 );`
10. Cleanup: `close(cap_stdout[0]); close(cap_stdout[1]); close(orig_stdin);`
11. The data you wanted are what the reading thread has read.

Note that the extra thread is needed because the pipe has a limited buffer space, and without the reader thread, the writes to the (piped) stdout would block, leading to deadlock inside the application.